# Differential equation without analytic solution - comparative statics

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, integral-equations

I am facing a differential equation - with boundary condition $v(T)$ given - without an analytic solution but still need to understand how the solution is affected by a change of the function's value.

$$ v(t) = v(T) - \int_t^T \dot{v}(s) ds $$

All I know is $\dot{v}(t)$ and $v(T)$. If I consider a change in a particular $v(s)$, I am interested in the effect on $v(t)$ for all $t<s$.
If I am not mistaken this should be given by

$$ \frac{d v(t)}{d v(s)} = - \int_t^s \frac{d\dot{v}(\tau)}{dv(\tau)}\frac{dv(\tau)}{dv(s)} d\tau.$$

The first part under the integral $\frac{d\dot{v}(\tau)}{dv(\tau)}$, I can quantify. However, the second is then again the same as the left-hand side. Is there a way to simplify this or a result that may apply to this and help studying this change?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

From the look of the equation, it tells us that

$$\int_t^s \dot{v}(s) ds$$

is an integral of acceleration that subracts from a given $v(T)$.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear about that: The differential equation is subject to a boundary condition $v(T)=v$.

Comment: Yes, you said you would want to look at the effect of v(s) on v(t), so you got to look at how will v(s) subtract from a given v(T)=v.